# Mac OSX - Use two network connections to the Internet

Tags: macos, networking, osx-mountain-lion

On my Mac Mini Mountain running Mountain Lion 10.8 I have two network connections to the Internet. One connection, the one currently being used by this very Safari browsing session, is also very busy uploading large files, hence using almost all the available bandwidth, anything else I try to do at the moment that requires web access takes ages. I cannot stop this file upload process, or would very much rather not.

So, I have also hooked up my phone via usb cable and activated its usb hotspot functionality, which I have used in the past and know to work like a charm.

My question is: how do I get another program, such as VMWare Fusion or another Safari session, to use the usb hotspot to connect to the Internet?

Thanks for any help,

Joe

Comment: I have found an answer to my own question, at least a portion of it. In VMWare Fusion it is possible to select the chosen network adapter from the menu Virtual Machine -> Network Adapter ->